# Order of arguments to find

Tags: find

```
0:root@SERVER:/tmp # find /tmp/foo* -mtime +74 -ls | wc -l
    1330
0:root@SERVER:/tmp # find /tmp/foo* -ls -mtime +74 | wc -l
    1750
0:root@SERVER:/tmp # oslevel -s
6100-09-04-1441
0:root@SERVER:/tmp # uname
AIX
0:root@SERVER:/tmp #
```

**Question:** Why doesn't find gives the same output?

Comment: @Thomas Please don't use OS tags on questions that are not OS-specific.

Answer (score 2):

Because you used the `-ls` operand, [`find`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm) returns true immediately and print the current path name, thus it cancelled default `-print`, there's no action after `-mtime +74`, it had no effect:

```
-ls             Always evaluates to the value True. Causes the current path name
                to be printed together with its associated statistics
```

If you did:

```
find . -ls -mtime +74 -print
```

then you got the aggregation from result of both operands.

Comment: `-mtime +74` has no effect because there's no action after that (and the presence of a `-ls` action predicate cancels the default `-print` action). If you had `find . -ls -mtime +74 -print`, all files would undergo `-ls` and the old ones `-print`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Right, updated to make it more accurate.